# Create tanget 45° div outside of body

Tags: html, css

I want to create a `div` outside of my `body` that is tilted by 45 degree that touches the `body` on the upper right edge and has with width according to the drawing.
This should be the case for arbitrary widths and heights of `body`.
This is how far I got but it doesn't quite do the trick yet.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="target">
   </body>
</html>

 .target {
    position: fixed;
    right: -50rem;
    width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }
```

[image: body and target-div]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on the `vw` and `vh` unit and some geometry

```css
.target {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(100vh/-1.414);
  left: calc(100vw - 100vw/1.414);
  height: 200vmax;/* big value here*/
  transform-origin: calc(100vw/1.414) 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background:red;
}

/* 1.414 = sqrt(2) */
```

```html
<div class="target"></div>
```

Here is another demo to better see the result:

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.target {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: calc(300px/-1.414);
  left: calc(400px - 400px/1.414);
  height: 700px;/* big value here*/
  transform-origin: calc(400px/1.414) 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background:red;
}

/* 1.414 = sqrt(2) */
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <div class="target"></div>
</div>
```